# Calling button click event from a sub without knowing the name of the button before running the sub

Tags: excel, vba, events, click

In a `Sub`, I would like to trigger a `Click` event. For a given Button, for example `ButtonCommand1`, I can do this by running the code:

```
    Sub test()

         Call Sheet1.ButtonCommand1_Click

    End sub
```

, where `ButtonCommand1_Click` is a `Public Sub` written in `Sheet1`.

However, my problem is that I don't know the name of the Button I would like to click on before running the sub itself. So I would need something like:

```
    Sub test()

         Dim i As Integer
         Dim button As String

         i = 'SOMETHING
         button = "ButtonCommand" & i 

         Call Sheet1.button_Click

    End sub
```

, where, again, the `Sub Sheet1.button_Click` would already be contained in `Sheet1` as a `Public Sub` for all possible `i`'s.

I have tried several options, namely setting button as an `Objec`t and playing with the `Shapes` collection in order to : 
`Set button = shapes.range(Array("ButtonCommand" & i)) AND i` also tried to select the correct shape by doing `shapes.range(Array("ButtonCommand" & i)).select` and then running `Application.Click`. But Nothing works. Thank you for your help!

Comment: application.run "ButtonCommand" & i

Comment: Why are you trying to go through the click handlers? Why not just call the appropriate method?

Comment: @Trs Of course, but undoubtedly this code will break if we are relying on click handlers (especially vaguely named click handlers) to run our pre-defined code. For example, how would I know the difference between `ButtonCommand1_Click` and `ButtonCommand5_Click`? What happens if someone with a lick of sense in them comes in and renames the buttons appropriately? For the record, anyone on my team who has a workbook with `Table19`'s and `ButtonCommand15`'s, etc will certainly hear about it, and fix it, before it goes into production.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `CallByName`

---

```
Sub test()

    Dim strName As String
    Dim i       As Long

    i = 1

    strName = "Button" & i & "_Click"
    CallByName Sheet1, strName, VbMethod


End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much @cyboashu! does exactly what I wanted!!

Answer (score 6):

You don't call event handlers. Handlers *handle events*, they're invoked by the VBA run-time in response to certain specific events.

Invoking event handlers "manually" is an anti-pattern in any language, VBA isn't an exception. Event handlers are `Private` by default, for a reason.

It's hard to tell exactly what you're doing with your example code, but say you have this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click()
    DoStuff
End Sub
```

And then somewhere else, you want to invoke that click handler - don't! Invoke `DoStuff` instead!

Answer (score 1):

`Application.Run "ButtonCommand" & i & "_Click"` should do it.

Comment: Why would you call an event handler through `Application.Run`? That is a really bad idea. While it may `work`, so does `ActiveSheet` or `ActiveCell`. There's a reason why we dont use these methods. They are prone to breaking. Also worth noting, there wont be a compile time error if the corresponding event handler doesnt exist. It will be a run-time error instead.

Answer (score 0):

I JUST dealt with this, and although cyboashu's answer got me really close to finding this, I stumbled upon another way which was the only way I was able to do it.  (My CommandButton is typically hidden and resides on a protected sheet - unsure if this made a difference in my efforts.)

From the Sub you call use something along these lines:

```
Sub Test()
    'Took me directly to the subroutine of the CommandButton using:
    Sheet1.CommandButton1 = True
End Sub
```